# How can I configure xlock to find fonts?

Tags: x11, fonts

Is it possible to make `xlock` to find fonts on my computer automatically? Namely, when I start xlock, it says

```
xlock: can not find font: -*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-24-*-*-*-*-*-*, using fixed...
```

In my computer there are at least the following fonts (excerpt from `xlsfonts`):

```
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-15
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-2
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-15
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-2
fixed
```

I know that I can use the following: `xlock -font -fixed` but I was wondering if it is possible for `xlock` to find suitable font without any parameters. And why

```
$ xlock -font -abobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1
xlock: can not find font: -abobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1, using fixed...`
```

won't work but `xlsfonts` lists that font?

I tried

```
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ xterm -fb -*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-24-*-*-*-*-*-*
xterm: cannot load font '-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-24-*-*-*-*-*-*'
xterm: cannot load font '-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-24-*-*-*-*-*-*'
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ xterm -fb -adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-43
xterm: cannot load font '-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-43'
xterm: cannot load font '-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-narrow--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-43'
```

and

```
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/xlock
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 129992 May 25  2012 /usr/bin/xlock
```

Comment: Does this font specification work with other traditional X applications such as xterm and xcolors? Is xlock setuid or setgid (`ls -l /path/to/xlock`)?